# css not working in IE9 or earlier versions

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am building a site which runs in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE10 perfectly but in IE9 css are not working properly for textbox and  round borders.

here is my site link
http://meetmentors.in/sohil/

for testing check this page also
http://meetmentors.in/sohil/registration.php

how can I make this to compatible with IE9 or earlier versions.

Comment: Please don't expect us to explore your site in detail in two different browsers trying to see what the differences are. You need to tell us what features aren't working, what you've done already to try to resolve the problem, and include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I am sorry for that. In the site textbox css is not working and in <div> borders are rounded. but not working in IE9

Comment: the borders are rounded becase border-radius is a css3 propert and wont work in earlier versions of ie. And the gray text in the textboxes is a property called placeholder(HTML5) which is again not available in ie9 and earlier versions.

Comment: @MarsOne: Thank you for showing me my errors but is there any solutions to solve that??

Comment: One thing you can do is use this website http://caniuse.com/#search=border to pinpoint exactly what you can and what you can't use on different browsers. Border-radius is supported by IE9 btw.

Comment: @SohilDesai, Check the solution i posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is an option where you can make the place-holder property work in earlier versions of IE.

You will have to include this JSlibrary.

> http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/assets/js/Placeholders.min.js

Try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VAKXL/2/) in IE9 and below. It should work.

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="This text will dissappear once you type"/>
```

Regarding your second query about the rounded div's check *[this link](http://css3pie.com/)*

Comment: I have checked it in IE8 & IE9. Still placeholder is not working in both and round borders are not working in IE8 but working properly in IE8

Comment: Im sorry. My bad. The link was bad Check the fiddle now. I have also updated my answer!